# Duplicated characters in a string

Tags: java

I do understand that I might find another threads/topics about "Duplicated characters in a string" but they all are completely different from my question.

I have created a simple hangman game, where I input the words I'm gonna use to play with, but if I enter a a word that has a duplicated character,  my whole program becomes useless and doesn't work properly. I do understand why it does so, because of the indexOf method, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Hangman game..");
    System.out.println("Enter the words you want to play with, '.' to exit");

    ArrayList <String> x=new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add(s.nextLine());

    for(int i=0;!(x.get(i).contains(".") && x.get(i).lastIndexOf(".")==x.get(i).length()-1);i++){
        x.add(s.nextLine());
    }

    x.set(x.size()-1, x.get(x.size()-1).substring(0, x.get(x.size()-1).length()-1));
    System.out.println("Okay, a word will be chosen randomly, try to guess it!");

    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int value = rand.nextInt(x.size()==1 ? x.size():x.size()-1)+0;
    char[] chr=new char[x.get(value).length()];
    for(int i=0;i<chr.length;i++){
        chr[i]='-';
        System.out.print(chr[i]);
    }

    char m;
    int n;
    Boolean r=true;

    while(r){
        m = s.next().charAt(0);
        n=x.get(value).indexOf(m);
        if(n!=-1)
            chr[n]=m;
        for(int j=0;j<chr.length;j++){
            System.out.print(chr[j]);           
        }

        if(new String(chr).indexOf('-') == -1){
            r=false;
            System.out.println("\nHangman!");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking here? How to detect a word with a duplicated character?

Comment: he is asking if there is a word like banana, then the game will hang because its contain duplicate characters.

Comment: @Pirate that's not a question: is he asking if the game will hang, or how to stop it hanging?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, exactly as Pirate said. If I the word is banana, the game will never end. It will never get out of the for-loop and will never complete the word, no matter what the input is

Comment: @Heshamy so, again, what are you actually asking? You are merely making a statement. Do you want to prevent words with repeated characters, or do you want to be able to handle them?

Comment: game is not hanging, actually the word is never complete and will be in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) method that takes two parameters, the character, and the index to start the search from. Calling it in a loop will reveal every occurrence of the given character.

Istead of

```
n=x.get(value).indexOf(m);
if(n!=-1)
   chr[n]=m;
```

You could write

```
int n = x.get(value).indexOf(m);
while(n!=-1) {
   chr[n] = m;
   n = x.get(value).indexOf(m, n + 1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot about the two parameters' one. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
String word = "thisandthat";
int pointer = 0;
List<Integer> tPositions = new ArrayList<>();
while((pointer=word.indexOf("t", pointer))!=-1){
    tPositions.add(new Integer(pointer++));
}
```

After the loop is finished it will have found all of the positions of "t" in the string.  This is because `indexOf()` can take two parameters the first being the search string and the second being the index to start from.  When the search string does not exist in the testable area `indexOf()` returns -1

Oh and you have to increment pointer by one:
     `tPositions.add(new Integer(pointer++));`
otherwise you will fall into an infinite loop because it will just continue to find the instance of the specified character.